# GTM send event when a given page parameter is true

Tags: google-tag-manager

I would like to track registration on my website using GTM and GA.
When a user register in my website, he will be redirected to the application and the URL will have the following parameter :
?welcome=true

In this case, I want to send a completeregistration event to GA. I succeed in creating a variable that get the value of the welcome parameter, but then I think something is wrong with my trigger.

Any ideas on how to deal with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a variable for this. A trigger like this should do:
[image]

Note that reloading the page will result in another event sent. You can prevent it by adding a logic to indicate that the event has already been sent and add a blocking trigger there that blocks the tag from firing if the your logic is present. Something simple like a five-minute cookie should suffice there. A transaction id blocking logic would be near perfect.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Indeed this trigger is working, but there is still something blocking my event from firing.
There is a filter wich is not satisfied : "_event equals gtm.js"
Do you have any idea how to solve this ?

PS : It looks like stackoverflow's servers are having issues so I can't upload any images atm

Thanks

Comment: If it's a new container, you have to publish it at least once, any version.